# FIRST_VALUE function not working as expected

Tags: sql, oracle, analytic-functions

I thought I understood how it works but now I am confused.

I have a dataset:

```
id date     value
1  20080101 null
2  20090101 34
3  20100101 null
```

Three records, from Jan 2008, 2009 and 2010. Now I want to create a new column "value2" with the latest non-null value. Basically I want a value2 column with 3 34s. I write:

```
select id, date, value, first_value(value) ignore nulls over (order by date desc) as value2 from table
```

However, I got:

```
id date     value   value2
1  20080101 null    34
2  20090101 34      34
3  20100101 null    null
```

The last value is still null not 34. What is going wrong here?

Comment: I found the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228910/whats-wrong-with-this-first-value-query

Answer (score 2):

The default window for analytic functions is `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` if you change it to `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` then you will get the desired result:

**Query 1**

```
WITH table_name AS (
            SELECT 1 AS id, TO_DATE( '20080101', 'YYYYMMDD' ) AS "date", NULL AS value FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, TO_DATE( '20090101', 'YYYYMMDD' ), 34   FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, TO_DATE( '20100101', 'YYYYMMDD' ), NULL FROM DUAL
)
SELECT id,
       "date",
       value,
       FIRST_VALUE( value IGNORE NULLS ) OVER (ORDER BY "date" DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) AS value2
FROM   table_name;
```

**Results**

```
ID  | date                   | VALUE   | VALUE2
-------------------------------------------------
3   | 2010-01-01 00:00:00    | (null)  | 34
2   | 2009-01-01 00:00:00    | 34      | 34
1   | 2008-01-01 00:00:00    | (null)  | 34
```

Answer (score 0):

Try eliminating the null valus in the order by clause

A possible solution might be

```
with x as (
    select 1  as id , 20080101 as ddate , null as v from dual union all 
    select 2 , 20090101 ,34 from dual union all 
    select 3 , 20100101 ,null from dual union all 
    select 4 , 20090101 ,15 from dual union all 
    select 5 , 20110101 ,null from dual union all 
    select 6 , 20120101 ,null from dual union all 
    select 7 , 20030101 ,55 from dual
) 
select  x.* , 
    first_value(v) over (order by case when v is null then null else ddate end) as last_nn_v
from    x
order by ddate
/

        ID      DDATE          V  LAST_NN_V
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         7   20030101         55         55
         1   20080101                    55
         4   20090101         15         55
         2   20090101         34         55
         3   20100101                    55
         5   20110101                    55
         6   20120101                    55
```

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting about the window. Default is RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW, meaning your value is being looked up in a window from first to current row. Your sorted rows are:

```
id date     value
3  20100101 null
2  20090101 34
1  20080101 null
```

- For id 1 the records 3, 2, 1 are in focus. Value 34 is found in the second row of these.
- For id 2 the records 3, 2 are in focus. Value 34 is found in the second row of these.
- For id 3 only the record 3 is in focus. Hence value 34 cannot be found.

BTW: There is a typo in your request: It is first_value(value ignore nulls), not first_value(value) ignore nulls.